# Formula to find part of a cell's value as exact match to a value from other cells

Tags: excel, formulas

On tab 1, I have data down column B that contains string values like this:

> \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Dan\Personal Folders 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Mike\My Stuff\Docs\Support 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Mike\My Stuff\Photos 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Bob\Plans

On tab 2, I have data down column C that I want to use as a lookup table like this:

> \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Adam 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Steve 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Mike 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Ronnie

I need a formula I can put on tab 1 down column C to see if any part of each text string from tab 1, column B matches any complete text string from tab 2, column C.  So for example, I would place this formula to show Yes or No like this:

> Column B......................................................................Column C
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Dan\Personal Folders....................No 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Mike\My Stuff\Docs\Support..........Yes 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Mike\My Stuff\Photos.....................Yes 
>   \\ABC\VOL1\DATA\Bob\Plans.......................................No

I have tried VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH, ISNUMBER/SEARCH, and COUNTIF as an array with wildcards, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.  Currently, with COUNTIF as array, I have this:

```
=COUNTIF(B2,"*" & 'Tab 2'!$C$2:$C$1000 & "*")
```

This is the start to return the array results, but the results aren't as I would expect as I get "0" when I should get "1" for certain rows.

If anyone can help me out with a formula (not VBA) using any of the functions mentioned above or any others, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: How come it's not all "Yes" in your output? All of your Column B values have `\\AVC\VOL1\DATA`, and that exists in each entry on tab 2.  Can you give some more examples perhaps?

Comment: I need any part of Column B to match the entire string in Column C...only the middle 2 do that in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH('Tab 2'!$C$2:INDEX('Tab 2'!$C:$C,MATCH("zzz",'Tab 2'!$C:$C)),B2)),"Yes","No")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott!  This ended up working just as I needed it to!

Comment: @DanB please mark one as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer you used.

Comment: I marked it, but I get a message that states "votes cast by people with less than 15 reputation points do not change then publicly displayed post score."  That's a gut punch to my personality :)

Comment: Not the down triangle the check mark below that. @DanB

Comment: Sorry. I have checked that now.

Answer (score 1):

This will search the cell for any of your criteria and return the number of matches if there is a match (which unless you have duplicates in the criteria it will be a 1).

Enter as array.

```
{=COUNT(SEARCH($C$1:$C$4,B1))}
```